# Show that spectral radius is lower than 1

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following matrix: $I - \frac{1}{h^2}\mu \Delta t  A$. Where $A$ is an NxN matrix. The eigenvalues of A $\lambda_j$ are given by $4sin^2(\frac{j\pi}{2(N+1)})$  for $j=1,...,N$. And $\mu , h, \Delta t > 0$.

Now I need to show that $\rho(I - \frac{1}{h^2}\mu \Delta t  A) < 1$ is satisfied when $\Delta t < \frac{1}{2\mu}h^2$. Where $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius of the matrix.

I'm not sure how to do this. My first step was to say that the eigenvalues of  $I - \frac{1}{h^2}\mu \Delta t  A$ are given by  $1 - \frac{1}{h^2}\mu \Delta t  \lambda_j(A)$. But I doubt this is correct since now it appears that it doesn't matter because this is never greater than 1 since the terms are all positive. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having the spectral radius bounded by $1$, it is not sufficient that the eigenvalues are smaller than $1$, they must be also larger than $-1$.The eigenvalues of $A$ lie in the interval $(0,4)$, so the eigenvalues of $I-\alpha A$ (where $\alpha>0$) lie in the interval $(1-4\alpha,1)$. So for having $\rho(I-\alpha A)<1$, we must have $-1<1-4\alpha$ and hence $\alpha <1/2$. With $\alpha=\mu\Delta t/h^2$, this gives $\Delta t<h^2/(2\mu)$.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! I forgot that the spectral radius was about the absolute value of the eigenvalues :). It makes sense now!